# C++ new pointer from pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I have a template linkedList that I would like to dynamically create "head" pointers for...

I seem unable to get any syntax to work.. my best guess is:

```
linkedList<int>** ptr;
ptr = new (linkedList<int>*)[1];
```

But it doesn't work. I'm fairly new to C++ so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Yo dawg, we heard you like pointers, so we pointed your pointer to a pointer so you can point to stuff while you point to stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a pointer, do:

```
T* ptr = new T;
```

where `T` is your type.
For a pointer-to-pointer, do:

```
T** ptrptr = new T*;
```

allocating the space for one pointer, which still needs to be filled like the first method:

```
*ptrptr = new T;
```

Now you got a valid pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: I get cast/assignment errors with my object when I try the code as suggested above.. Do I need to create a constructor for T* in the definition of class T?

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you are not using std::list? (or std::forward_list)

Check out the header files for std::list, or your nearest C++ book, or in fact
cppreference.com

Your linked list class template should have a function to return the head of the list. Look at std::list::begin() in your compiler's c++ library. The std::list::iterator type is a pointer to whatever goes in the list. (ie T*)

Comment: My data structures class doesn't allow the use of std, sadly.

Comment: Using STL data structures would defeat the purpose of a data structures class - in using STL, you do not learn of the implementation of various structures.

Comment: @RageD: The homework tag wasn't present when I answered, although I suspected. For that reason I specifically call out studying the code. Surely studying a reference interface for a linked list template is a valuable way to spend your time in a data structures class.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not sure pointer array is really needed for your linked
list, as for just `new` construct, the following form will be compiled.

```
ptr = new (linkedList<int>*[1]);
```

**EDIT**:
This allocates pointer array:

```
linkedList<int>** ptr = new (linkedList<int>*[1]);
```

This allocates array:

```
linkedList<int>* ptr = new linkedList<int>[1];
```

This allocates one element:

```
linkedList<int>* ptr = new linkedList<int>;
```

Comment: This seems exactly like what I need, but g++ in cygwin complains:
`error: cannot convert 'linkedList<int>**' to 'linkedList<int>*' in assignment.`
All I need is a "new" NULL pointer to insert into the AVL Tree. The array notation was just my best guess. Is something along the lines of `ptr = new (linkedList<int>*);` possible? I tried it, it's not.. but is there anything similar? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I see the error, the type of `ptr` and `new` expression seem
to be mismatched.
Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the head of a linked list would look something like:

```
node<int> *head = NULL;
```

When you want to create and insert a node, you'd use something like:

```
insert(node<int> *&list, int value) { 
// insert new node containing `value` at head of `list`.

    node<int> *temp = new node(value);

    temp->next = list;
    list=temp;
}
```

You could use this something like:

```
node<int> *list = NULL;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    insert(list, i);
```

Of course, unless this is for homework (or something on that order), you should stop working on this immediately, and just `std::list` (or `boost::slist`, if you want a singly-linked list).

Edit: I'm adding more detail mentioned by the OP in comment. For the moment, the `avl_tree::insert` does *not* attempt to maintain balance. It's just a plain-jane un-balanced insert, but it should be adequate to demonstrate what we care about at the moment.

```
template <class T>
struct linked_list { 
    node *head;

    void insert(T v) {
        node<T> *n = new node(v, head);
        head = n;
    }

    linked_list() : head(NULL) {}

    template <class T>
    struct node { 
        node *next;
        T data;

        node(T const &v, node *n=NULL) : data(v), next(n) {}
    };
};

template <class keyType, class dataType>
class avl_tree { 
    struct node {
        node *left, *right;
        char balance;
        keyType key;
        dataType data;

        node(keyType const &k, dataType const &d) 
            : left(NULL), right(NULL), balance(0), key(k), data(d)
        { }

        bool operator<(node const &other) { 
            return key < other.key;
        }
    } *root;

    bool insert(node const *new_node, node *&tree) { 
        if (tree == NULL) {
            tree = new_node;
            return true;
        }
        else if (*new_node < *tree)
            return insert(new_node, tree->left);
        else if (*new_node > *tree)
            return insert(new_node, tree->right);
        else // new_node == tree
            return false; // couldn't insert -- already present.
    }

public:

    avl_tree() : root(NULL) {}

    void insert(keyType const &key, dataType const &data) { 
        node *temp = new node(key, data);
        insert(temp, root);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is for an assignment. The idea is that I have an AVL Tree with ItemType linkedList<int>*, representing the head of a linked list.
I am trying to insert nodes onto the AVL Tree, each with its own new linkedList<int>* head. I am not allowed modify the AVL Tree source code, so I have to somehow start and maintain a linked list for each AVL Tree node. Since I am populating my AVL Tree from within a while loop, however, my pointers are either deleted (if defined within the loop) because of scope, or I only have one pointer, which is set to be the head of every AVL node.

Comment: The linked list being built into an AVL tree node shouldn't really change much (if anything).

Comment: The main problem is that I have to declare the AVL Tree in the form `AVL< string, linkedList<int>* > myTree;`. So I cannot program a concrete node into the AVL Tree. I'm left guessing at how to use AVL Tree `bool insert(string,linkedList<int>*)` to in essence achieve the same effect.